# Flow error message

Tags: solutions

When I am selecting the Solution for the topic, I see the below error comes.

> Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow
>    M. The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID XXXXXXXXXXXX. Flow error messages: <b>An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow</b><br>An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information. Contact your administrator for help.

```
Close this tab to continue.
```

Comment: The error email that Clint mentions has the details that are needed to debug.  The message the user recieves does not have any info to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time a flow fails, the admin who created the associated flow gets an email. The email includes the error message of the failure and details about every flow element that's executed

This will help you in debugging the issue.